# can repeated submission of papers omitting main contributor considered as plagiarism?will the journals retract such articles?

Tags: publications, journals, ethics, plagiarism, research-misconduct

I have completed my MTech in an elite institute in India. During my tenure, my professor forced me to collaborate with a Part-time Phd student, hence the work had to be shared data, analysis & drafts though this person had no contribution other than proofreading. We had published the article in conference proceedings with my name as the first author. Later the article was published by the Phd student & supervisor without my consent & omitted my name. On contacting they refused to accept the request to add my name as the first author even though the work was based on my thesis. I contacted the editor & the paper was withdrawn. later I managed to publish a book based on my thesis. After 2 years I noticed the same team had published the exact same article in two other journals which was again a copy from the thesis. This time one article was in press & other article published. The article in the press is now withdrawn other under investigation.

Update: I want to know what I can do to prevent them doing again? I don't want to collaborate with them anymore. So should i publish papers without them? PhD student had no role but my supervisor guided me. So it will be ethically wrong not to include my supervisor . Should I still proceed without them since they had been unfair ?what is the best solution? The current papers they published were based on my thesis which was published as a book by me. Thanks for the answers.

Comment: There is no question. What would you like us to help you with?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Publishing a paper omitting the main contributor is plagiarism, as well as an ethical violation. Publishing an already-published paper isn't plagiarism (assuming the original authors haven't changed), but it almost surely violates a journal's originality policies. Both will likely lead to retraction. The first will require hard proof, but the second shouldn't take more than mailing the publisher/journal with the already-published article.

Comment: Re-publishing a paper will also likely violate copyright agreements made with the original publisher.